# Error al insertar un array en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

debí crear este recorrido de un array ya que requiero insertar mas de 1 millon de registros en mysql y hacer un insert por registro me arroja error, encuentro que lo ideal es hacer un insert masivo pero al momento de ejecutar me arroja este error. (Notice: Array to string conversion in). que estoy haciendo mal?

```
foreach ($datosarray as $a=>$b){
    $query = "INSERT INTO mesanterior VALUES";

    foreach($b as $c => $d){
        $query.= " ($d),";
    }
    $query = substr($query,0,-1);
    mysqli_query($conn,$query);
}
```

Comment: Puedes agregar un poco de qué tiene adentro la variable `$b` de favor

Comment: ¿Qué contiene la variable **$d**?

Comment: Puede que haya arrays anidados en el array que intentas insertar. En cualquier caso recomendaría que uses transacciones para hacer inserciones masivas. Así, si la inserción falla en algún punto podrás revertir todo. Sin hacerlo así va a ser difícil cotejar luego qué datos se insertaron y qué datos no se pudieron insertar en caso de algún fallo.